# Matlab split string multiple delimiters

Tags: regex, string, matlab, split, tokenize

I have a cell list of strings like this:

```
cellArr = 
      'folderName_fileName_no.jpg',
      'folderName2_fileName2_no2.jpg'
```

I want to get it like this

```
{folderName, fileName, no},
{folderName2, fileName2, no2}
```

How to do it in matlab?
I know I can use

```
regexp(cellArr, '_', 'split'),
```

but how can I use more than one delimiters?

Comment: Have you heard of `fileparts`, `fullfile`, `pathsep` and similar tools? These tools probably prevent this whole problem...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found it.. Thanks for the replies..

```
regexp(cellArr, '[_.]', 'split')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very similar to the C method of string tokenization. Using `strtok`, you can tokenize based on whichever delimiter you choose ( in your case '_' )

[STRTOK reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtok.html)

Note, you will use the C idiom of repeatedly calling `strtok` in a loop on its remaining string as it returns only the first token each time. An example is given in the reference.

To answer your EDIT:

> Using strtok on a cell array of strings returns a cell array of strings in token and a character array in remain:

```
s = {'all in good time'; ...
 'my dog has fleas'; ...
 'leave no stone unturned'};

remain = s;

for k = 1:4
   [token, remain] = strtok(remain);
   token
end
```

straight from example 3 in the reference. < To make it quite obvious, you just replace `strtok(remain)` with `strtok(remain,REQUIRED_DELIMITERS)` and add trivial logic to drop the file extension.

Comment: How can I use REQUIRED_DELIMITERS? could you please give me an example?

Comment: @user570593 REQUIRED_DELIMITERS in your case would be '_.', a string containing all the delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

It also useful to do using `strsplit`:

```
cellArr = 
      'folderName_fileName_no.jpg',
      'folderName2_fileName2_no2.jpg'

C = strsplit(cellArr,'_')
```

Then C is a cell array containing the three vectors. Also there is `filepath` if it's needed to remove parts not necessary, like extensions. `strsplit` can also be used with Regex if it needs to!